# Connecting Angular HTTP With TypeORM Controller / Nestjs - These Work But Secure?

Tags: angular, typeorm, nestjs

I'm nervous about designing security into my code.  I have this code working properly but is it the optimum for security or are there better ways of doing CRUD and queries?  I'm including full CRUD and a couple of queries here as examples for others.  So far this is almost nothing on the Web about how Angular and Nestjs / TypeORM come together.  This should help fill that gap for those of us new to the server side.  I would love suggestions for improvement and discussion since I have no confidence I'm getting this right.

Below are both the TypeORM repository find options method and the Query Builder method.  Not sure which is best or if it matters.

Angular httpService.service

```
// ---- GET all records. ----

  public getAllRecords(dbTable: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get<any>(`${this.api}${dbTable}`);
  }


// ---- CREATE new record ---

  public addRecord(dbTable: string, recordData):  Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .post(`${this.api}${dbTable}`, recordData, {headers: this.headers});
  }


// ---- FETCH record detail for editing or viewing. ----

  public getRecordById(dbTable: string, recordId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get<any>(`${this.api}${dbTable}/${recordId}`);
  }


// ---- UPDATES an existing record ----

  public updateRecord(dbTable: string, recordId: number, recordUpdate): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .patch(`${this.api}${dbTable}/${recordId}`, recordUpdate, {headers: this.headers});
  }


// ---- DELETES a single record. ----

  public deleteRecord(dbTable: string, recordId: number):  Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .delete(`${this.api}${dbTable}?id=${recordId}`, {headers: this.headers});
  }


  // ---------------- QUERIES ------------------------------



  // --------- INCREMENTAL SEARCH --------

  //  Called by the Mat Data Table filter to search db by user name.
  public nameSearch(dbTable, column, terms) {
    return terms.pipe(
      tap(x => console.log('3 service called')),
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(term => {
        console.log('4 term: ', term);
        const url = `${this.api}${dbTable}/${column}/${term}`;
        return this.http.get(url);
      }),
      catchError((error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
        return of();
      }),
    );
  }


  // ------------- SEARCH COUNTRIES ---------------------
  //  Called from main components to search for users by country.

  public searchCountries(dbTable, column, country): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.api}${dbTable}/${column}/${country}`);
  }
```

TypeORM and the Nestjs controller, the api end point:

```
@Controller('api/members')  // /members route
export class MembersController {
  constructor(private readonly membersService: MembersService) {}


  /* --------------- CRUD -------------------- */


  @Get()
  async findAll(): Promise<Members[]> {
    return await this.membersService.findAll();
  }

  @Get('/:id')
  async findItem(@Param() recordId): Promise<Members> {
    return this.membersService.findItem(recordId.id);
  }

  @Post()  // Adding the dto type to recordData made no difference.
  async addItem(@Req() req, @Body() recordData): Promise<Members> {

    const result: Members = await this.membersService.addItem(recordData);
    if (!result)
      throw new HttpException('Error adding new Member', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    return result;
  }

  @Patch('/:id')
  async updateItem(@Param() recordId: number, @Body() recordUpdate) {
    const result = await this.membersService.updateItem(recordId, recordUpdate);
    if (!result)
      throw new HttpException('Error updating Member', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    return result;
  }

  @Delete()
  async deleteItem(@Query() recordId) {
    return await this.membersService.deleteItem(recordId.id);
  }



  /* ---------------------  QUERIES -------------------- */


  // Called from Angular last name search() in http.service. User inputs words by letter to search.

  @Get('/last_name/:entry')
  public async wordSearch(@Param('entry') entry) {
    const result = await this.membersService.wordSearch(entry);
    if (!result)
      throw new HttpException('Error searching last name', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    return result;
  }


  // Called from searchCountries in Angular http.service.
  @Get('/country/:country')
  public async searchCountries(@Param('country') country) {
    const result = this.membersService.searchCountries(country);
    if (!result)
      throw new HttpException('Error searching last name', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is really needed is a blog post that explains how all this works but I'm not competent enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to validate any user input from `@Param()` and `@Body()` parameters. Typically you can have some fields internally managed which should not be user-controlled.

Ex, "deleted" field, or read-only fields with some statistics.

Take a look on [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) and [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) packages

Comment: Thank you Alexey.  I'm validating my forms with Angular like this:  `first_name: ['', Validators.required],`  I just made a custom validator for unique user name and make more this week.   It seems that the typestack packages do some or all of what Angular does, but I'm no expert at this.  Good to see pleerock contributing.  I send him money for TypeORM.